# Block key press using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code to block key press but I can't block these keys:

```
{ } | ~
```

How can i add that to my code ?

```
<html><head>
<script>
function ort(){
if ((event.keyCode > 32 && event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode < 65) || (event.keyCode > 90 && event.keyCode < 97)){event.returnValue = false;}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onSubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" onKeyPress="ort()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the keys you do and do not want to block?

Comment: this 4 keys:
 { }  ~ |

Comment: Are you trying to block them from being pressed anywhere on the page, or specific area?  (inputs, textares, etc)

Comment: Right, but, it might make more sense to block all keys except for the ones you want depending on what you want.

Comment: @JonathanM events are always case insensitive. However, you may need to change the event (`onKeypress` to `onKeydown` or something... I don't remember)

Comment: @soktinpk, ah, yes, thanks for the reminder. There is a `onkeypress`.

Comment: @عمارالسورى, bro, your profile pic is completely offensive. We don't care who's side you're on. Don't denegrate here. Please change it.

Comment: i had test correct 'onKeypress' to 'onKeyPress' but this keys '{ } | ~' un blocked also thanks any way, :)

Comment: @عمارالسورى, yeah, sorry for the wrong answer. We'll work to get a good one for you.

Comment: @JonathanM No problem my friend .. `onKeypress` was fault all the conditions. thanks

Comment: @عمارالسورى, glad you found the answer...and thanks for changing the profile picture, brother.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to find all character codes:
http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

You can use CTRL-F to find what character code you need.

```
function ort() {
     // if { OR } OR | OR ~ are pressed. (Character codes 122-127)
     if ((event.keyCode >  32 && event.keyCode <  48) || 
   (event.keyCode >  57 && event.keyCode <  65) ||
   (event.keyCode >  90 && event.keyCode <  97) ||
   (event.keyCode > 122 && event.keyCode < 127)) {

        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry the the function should be named ort(event) and the same should be reflected in the html (onkeydown="ort(event)")

Comment: but the function is play now in my web site with out change that !

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XygT2/).

The *key* is to check for all the key codes returned for each of the browsers, since they vary a little bit. I found a [key code table](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm) with this data:

```
        keydown/keyup event.keyCode                    
Opera   MSIE  Firefox  Safari  Chrome    Key pressed
_________________________________________________________
188     188     188     188     188      , <
190     190     190     190     190      . >
191     191     191     191     191      / ?
192     192     192     192     192      ` ~
219     219     219     219     219      [ {
220     220     220     220     220      \ |
221     221     221     221     221      ] }
222     222     222     222     222      ' "
```

Clearly, the keys you wanted to suppress are in a different range from what you expected.
Here's the new keypress handler:

```
function ort(event) {
   if ((event.keyCode >  32 && event.keyCode <  48) || 
       (event.keyCode >  57 && event.keyCode <  65) ||
       (event.keyCode >  90 && event.keyCode <  97) ||
       (event.keyCode > 122 && event.keyCode < 127))
   {
       event.returnValue = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but must change this :
`function ort(event)` to `function ort(evt)`
and in html
`onKeyPress="ort()"` to `onKeyPress="ort(event)"`
the code is true after that :)